# Using get_term() in functions.php results in Invalid taxonomy error

Tags: loop, taxonomy, terms

I don't know why `get_term()` works on other pages but won't work in `functions.php`. Using `get_term()` in `functions.php` causes WordPress to report the error *Invalid taxonomy*.

my `function.php` which is ajax handler and already registered for ajax

```
 public function load_destination()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $termId = $_POST['termid']; 
       $term =  get_term($termid,'package_state');
       $args = array(
'post_type' => 'package',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'package_state',
    'field' => 'id',
    'terms' => $termId
     )
  )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$collection=[];
$count =1;
while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

$collection['data'][] = // i need to set term data here $term;


$count++;
endwhile;
    wp_send_json($collection);    
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are are using `get_term()` for a custom taxonomy. If you're using `get_term()` inside `functions.php` and outside of a hooked function, that code is going to be run immediately when `functions.php` is loaded. Your custom taxonomy will not have been registered at this point, because that happens on the `init` hook.

Your code is working inside of your page template because WordPress has loaded the custom taxonomies at that point.

If you were to try something like `$term = get_term( '2', 'category' );` (where `2` is a valid term ID) in `functions.php`, it would actually work, because WordPress loads built-in taxonomies in `wp-settings.php` (which is very early in the loading process) for backwards compatibility reasons. WordPress also registers default taxonomies on `init`, by the way. This is explained in the documentation block for `create_initial_taxonomies()` in [`/wp-includes/taxonomy.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L13).

Anyway, running `get_term()` outside of a hooked function in `functions.php` is not the right way to do it, and more code would be needed to help you further.

Comment: so how could i get this task done as i was working on ajax so i need to load an term object and show but couldnt load it damn me

Comment: Without showing your code, I don't know. This answer already required the limits of my mind reading capabilities ;-)

Comment: i have updated my code

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term

```
Uses global: (object) $wpdb
```

try declaring

```
global $wpdb;
```

before your get_term() query?

It may work, depending on the code you're trying to use.

Comment: no its aint working still getting invalid taxonomy but same stuff works over other pages except functions.php

Comment: You'll have to post the code you're trying to working with.  Edit your original post

Comment: the code is same get_term() but the use of code is different one is functions.php and other is page.php

Comment: Post the code from your `functions.php`.

Comment: $test = get_term(8,'package_state'); var_dump($test)